getting all the links - that are "stored" in the page: i tried to invest the page thoughroghly
how to  get all the links - that are "stored" in the page
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/gaestewohnung-finden/teilnehmende-genossenschaften
tried to search in the basic-text of the page!
i tried to invest the page thoughroghly..i have seen  the listing of approx 100 links.
but did not manage to extract them all at once
update:  tried out this one: - with BS4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

source_code = requests.get('https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/gaestewohnung-finden/teilnehmende-genossenschaften')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.content, 'lxml')
links = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(str(link))


Does this answer your question? How extract all URLs in a website using BeautifulSoup

yes - i am a bit familiar with BS4. Many thanks for the hint. Awesome!

dearJonSG - i am very thankful  - i allready tried it out. But at the moment with no success - will continue to triy it out

You can probably get the links you seek via BS4. and using the select() method to pass in a css selector.
Try:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source_code = requests.get('https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/gaestewohnung-finden/teilnehmende-genossenschaften')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code.text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.select('li a'):
    link_url = link["href"]
    if link_url.startswith("http"):
        print(link_url)

that should give you:
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/gaestewohnung-finden
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/gaestewohnung-finden/guestflats
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/gaestewohnung-finden/teilnehmende-genossenschaften
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/aktuelles
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/aktuelles/news
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/aktuelles/internationaler-tag-der-genossenschaften-1-juli-2023
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/genossenschaften
https://www.wohnungsbaugenossenschaften.de/genossenschaften/wie-funktioniert-genossenschaft
...


many many thanks - thats just awesome!! you have helped me alot!!!

many thanks dear JonSG - glad that you showed me a way. Awesome.
have  a great day.
